# Microsoft Face API (Android)- Add Person to Person Group

Tags: android, azure, exception, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I know that this may seem to be a rather broad question, but I have been unable to figure out **how to create a Person in a Person Group using the Microsoft Face API in Android Studio**.

I have tried the following code to make a `CreatePersonResult` object in Android:

```
try {
    CreatePersonResult person1 = faceServiceClient.createPerson(personGroupId, "Bob", "My Friends");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created Person called Bob", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Creation failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

The above code outputs: **"Creation failed: null"** which means that **the `Exception` was `null`** for some reason.

In Visual Studio, to create a `Person` I simply have to do the following:

```
CreatePersonResult person1 = await faceServiceClient.CreatePersonAsync(personGroupId, "Bob");
```

---

Does anyone know how I can create the `Person` in a Person Group in Android? I have been unable to figure out how to do this in Android, but found plenty of tutorials for Visual Studio.